# When will we know who won the election?

Tags: support, election

Ok.

The moderator election closes in ~3 hours, and I was just wondering how long after it was closed will we know who the winners were?

Will the winners have to accept the moderator agreement before the results can be displayed? Is this all done automatically, or does it require human intervention?

P.S

I was wondering whether to ask this here or MSO - which one should it have been?

Comment: Asking here is fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you see a post here on meta titled "2012 Community Moderator Election Results" you'll be able to read it and know what the results were. That'll usually happen somewhere between 10 minutes and 24 hours after the election ends.

Of course, someone will probably post the results in chat between 10 and 24 seconds after the election ends.

But if that's still not quick enough for you, you can download the OpenSTV software and election data and run it yourself (both will be linked to on the election page immediately after the election ends). How long that takes is up to you.

Comment: I ran Android's results second, so it ended up taking [52 seconds](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7201135#7201135). My bad, everyone.

Comment: I was in bed when it ended (which was at midnight). No matter, I lost anyway.

Comment: Well, you got a respectable number of votes none the less.

Comment: @Shog9 If you can call 16 a respectable number, anyhow lets not chat via comments.